# PHP How to refer to a class method definition?

Tags: php

I would like to bind a function (a method of a class) to another class. Any idea of how i could achieve this?
Here is an example of what i want:

```
class A {
  protected $prop = "prop A";

  function method($arg1, ...) {
    return $this->prop;
  }    
}

class B {
  protected $prop = "prop B";

  // need help here
}
```

So i want to "bind" the method "method" of class "A" to class "B" so it'll be possible to do `$b = new B(); $b->method($arg1, ...);` and obtain `"prop B"`;

Thanks in advance!!

I tried:

```
class B {
  protected $instance;
  protected $prop = "prop B";

  public function __construct($instance) {
    $this->instance = $instance;
  }

  public function __call($method, $args) {
    return call_user_func_array([$this->instance, $method], $args);
  }
}

$b = new B(new A());
$b->method();
```

But still outputing "prop A";
I tried this too:

```
class B {
  protected $prop = "prop B";

  public function __call($method, $args) {
    return call_user_func_array(Closure::bind($this->$method, $this, get_called_class()), $arguments);
  }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$b->method = $a->method;
$b->method();
```

But i'm getting this error: `Closure::bind() expects parameter 1 to be Closure, null given...`.
At last i tried this too:

```
class B {
  protected $instance;
  protected $prop = "prop B";

  public function __construct($instance) {
    $this->instance = $instance;
  }

  public function __call($method, $args) {
    $new_method = $this->instance->$method->bindTo($this);

    return call_user_func_array($new_method, $args);
  }
}

$b = new B(new A());
$b->method();
```

Here, an error says `$this->instance->$method` is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dependency injection, you can access the passed object:

```
class A {
  public function speak() { return ‘meow’; }
}

class B {
  public function __construct($obj) {
    $this->a = $obj;
  }
}

$demo = new B( new A));
print $demo->a->speak();
// => meow
```

From here, if you want B->speak to refer to A->speak:

```
class A {
  public function speak() { return ‘meow’; }
}

class B {
  public function __construct($obj) {
    $this->a = $obj;
  }

  public function speak() {
    return $this->a->speak();
  }
}

$demo = new B( new A));
print $demo->a->speak(); // meow
print $demo->speak(); // meow
```

Or, if B is a special kind of A:

```
// use obj A above

class B extends A {
  // do stuff B knows
}

$demo = new B;
print $demo->speak();
// => meow
```

If you’re wanting the exact same method in both classes, perhaps what you’re looking for is traits.  Traits are more or less an include for objects which lets objects “share” code. (Personally I think it’s a fancy way of violating DRY and is better handled with DI... but smarter people than I have included it in the language)

Using traits would be something like this (double check docs, I’ve never used this)

```
trait sharedMethod {
  public function speak() {
    return $this->prop;
  }
}

class A {
  use sharedMethod;
  public $prop = “I’m from A”;
}

class B {
  use sharedMethod;

  public $prop = “I’m from B”;

  public function __construct(object $a) {
    $this->a = $a;
  }

  /**
   * use this to get A’s method, or omit to keep B’s method 
   */
  public function speak() {
    return $this->a->speak();
  }
}

$demo = new B( new A));
print $demo->speak(); // I’m from A


// if you don’t override the method

$demo = new B( new A));
print $demo->speak(); // I’m from B
```

Comment: Let take your first example as it's the closest one to my question. Now let consider class A has a protected property `$prop = "Some class A prop"` as well class B too has `$prop = "Some class B prop"`, and the `speak` method returns instead `$this->prop`. `print $demo->a->speak()` will output `Some class A prop` instead of `Some class B prop` (exactly what i want). Now the problem with extending class B from class A is that I can't override a static method as a non-static, for instance if `speak` were static it won't be possible to override it in class B as non-static what indeed is my goal.

Comment: Expanded my answer. I forgot what your requirements were and initially went the wrong direction. But I think traits are what you’re after